# Parse the output of an expect variable and use it in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, expect

I have a bash script that uses expect inside the bash script.  This bash script will prompt for a password inside the expect part of the script and then return some output.  I want to take that output and parse it so that it only displays a part of the output to me and stores that in a variable that the normal bash script can use.  My script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

output=$(
/usr/bin/expect << EOF
spawn -noecho generate passcode -a 123456789
expect "passphrase:" { send "password\n" }
expect eof
EOF
#)
) | awk '/^ [a-zA-Z]*: (\S+)/'

echo $output
```

The output that I get without the awk regex is:
`Passcode: 543245324532455464`
My regex will parse the output and only store the `543245324532455464` value in the output variable.  That is what I hoped it would do.  If I append the `| awk '/^ [a-zA-Z]*: (\S+)/'` to the end of the command, it returns nothing, just blank.  If I take it off, it returns the output I expect.

Can anyone tell me how I can get the correct data stored into my variable in bash?

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!  That was it.

Answer (score 2):

As written, you capture the output of /usr/bin/expect then pipe nothing to awk - the closing parenthesis of the command substitution needs to go at the end of the pipeline

not

```
... ) | awk '/^ [a-zA-Z]*: (\S+)/'
```

but

```
... | awk '/^ [a-zA-Z]*: (\S+)/')
```

---

Be aware that `\S` is non-standard (PCRE) and may not be supported in all versions of awk and that the capture group likely won't have any effect - you might do better with something like

```
awk -F': ' '$1 ~ /Passcode/ {print $2}'
```